# allow null value for sequelize foreignkey?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

How do I allow null for a foreignkey? I have a `through` and `belongsToMany` association:

```
Shelf
    belongsToMany(Book, { through: Library, as: "Books"});

Book
    belongsToMany(Shelf, { through: Library, as: "Shelves"});

Library
    section: DataTypes.STRING,
    // ... other fields
```

I would like to record a `null` on the `bookId` in `Library`:

```
Library.create({
    section: "blah",
    bookId: null,
    shelfId: 3
});
```

Since Sequelize automatically creates the `bookId` and `shelfId` in the join table `Library`, how would I specify that I want to allow a `null` on the `bookId` foreignkey in `Library`?

Answer (score 27):

I am no expert on `node.js` nor `sequelize.js`, but with one search in google I got the [official documentation](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/associations/). You might need to pay some attention to this part of the code in the documentation:

```
Library.hasMany(Picture, {
  foreignKey: {
    name: 'uid',
    allowNull: false
  }
});
```

It seems you need to specify the `{foreignKey: {name: 'bookId', allowNull: true} }` in `Library`.

Comment: I tried that, but it still refuses to allow null: `{ through: Library, as: "Books", foreignKey: { name: 'bookId', allowNull: true }}` gives `null value in column "bookId" violates not-null constraint`

Comment: Did you try adding `{foreignKey:{...}, constraints: false}` ?

Comment: Note: Approved @farhan-yaseen's changes since I had a few typos in the copied code. Thanks!

Comment: I am a bit late to this thread, but I was also going through the same thing, Can you guys point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

By default, the Sequelize association is considered optional. If you would like to make the foreign key required, you can set `allowNull` to be `false`.

```
Foo.hasOne(Bar, {
  foreignKey: {
    allowNull: false
  }
});
```

[See the docs](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#:%7E:text=Bar.belongsTo(Foo)%3B-,Mandatory%20versus%20optional%20associations,-By%20default%2C%20the)